# ASP.NET MVC: Check if binded model was actually passed to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an action with a FilterModel passed to it. I use a search to pass the filter to the action or I call the action without passing a filter to it. When I call it normally, the filter is instantiated (which I did not expect to happen). How do I check that no filter was actually passed?

My model:

```
public class ProductFilterModel
{
    //Using a constructor so the search view gets a default value.
    public ProductFilterModel()
    {
        MinPrice = 500;
        MaxPrice = 1000;
    }

    public int MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int MaxPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Index(ProductFilterModel filter){
    //How do I check if no filter was passed?
}
```

The normal call to the action is: `localhost/Products` while a filtered call would be `localhost/Products?MinPrice=5&MaxPrice=100`

When my action receive a call normally, the filter gets defaulted to the values set above, so I cannot even check to see if `MinPrice` is 0 to know to load it normally.

Comment: Can you post a short snippet showing the 'normal' call that instantiates the filter?

Comment: sounds like a case for the good old' *isDirty* flag

Comment: @Alex - I edited question. @RPM1974 - What is that?

Comment: @Shawn McLean - it's an *old school* programming technique to determine if a value has changed. It's a messy technique (and a last resort). Let's see if we can find a better solution. Can you show your route? (i want to double-check how your populating that model in your route)

Comment: @RPM1984 - I did not edit the route in the global.ascx file. Unless you mean a different route.

Comment: @Shawn Mclean - right, i forgot it uses reflection to figure uot to populate the properties. But this is usually for `[HttpPost]`, not `[HttpGet]` (which is what your action is accepting). I would recommend not passing through the strongly typed model for the get, just have the params `int MinPrice, int MaxPrice`, then *explicitly* create the viewmodel in the action, where you could check if the property has a value already. Know what i mean? Leave the creation of the ViewModel to you. (not MVC's reflection smarts). Will put as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check ModelState.Count. If ModelState.Count == 0 then no values were set to your model during binding.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Make `MinPrice`, `MaxPrice` nullable, so that I can only filter either on Min or Max and not on both.
2. Not set the default on the ViewModel.
3. Set the default from the action, where the filter is created.
4. Implement `Index` as following:

(Assume you always have the filter)

```
public ActionResult Index(ProductFilterModel filter){
    filter = filter ?? new ProductFilterModel();
    if (filter.MinPrice.HasValue)
       FilterOnMin();
    if (filter.MaxPrice.HasValue)
        AlsoFilterOnMax();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the view model for both display and submission of data so why not use 2 constructors therefore making your intent far more explicit?

```
public class ProductFilterModel
{
  private int? _minPrice;
  private int? _maxPrice;

  public class ProductFilterModel( int defaultMinPrice, int defaultMaxPrice )
  {
    MinPrice = defaultMinPrice;
    MaxPrice = defaultMaxPrice;
  }

  public class ProductFilterModel()
  {
  }

  public int MinPrice
  {
    get { return _minPrice.HasValue ? _minPrice.Value ? 0; }
    set { _minPrice = value; }
  }

  public int MaxPrice
  {
    get { return _maxPrice.HasValue ? _maxPrice.Value ? Int32.MaxValue; }
    set { _maxPrice = value; }
  }

  public bool HasFilter
  {
    get { return _minPrice.HasValue || _maxPrice.HasValue; }
  }
}
```